# Is it possible to make Android Studio use a specific key store when building debug APK?

Tags: android-studio, push-notification, android-keystore

I do not want Android Studio to use the (automatically created) debug.keystore, instead I want to use my release keystore. The reason for this is that Push Notifications do not work when the APK is signed with the debug key.

I *have* googled, but I cannot find a way.

Answer (score 0):

The change you want is in your `build.gradle`, not in Android studio itself, per-se. You can configure the signing keystore using Android Studio, but under the hood your build.gradle will be edited by the IDE. The documentation is available [here](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html).

The section on [securing your key](https://developer.android.com/studio/publish/app-signing.html#secure-key) describes how to add this into your `build.gradle` in a secure/safe way, assuming you don't want your signing details checked into version control.